# How can I invoke a function after the user has stopped clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, rest, api, angular

If I have a online shopping platform, I want to call my REST API after the user stops clicking the add button.

Let's say that he wants 10 products, and he starts clicking the "add" button. I don't want to make a call every time the user presses the "add" button. I want to know when the user stops clicking and then make a call to my server with the quantity = 10.

btw I'm using Angular2.

Comment: How are you going to know the user won't press it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `setTimeout(backendCallback, ms)` on each click. If clicked again - clear timeout and repeat.

```
let timer;
let callbackDealy = 800;

onAddClick(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.http.get().subscribe(...);
    }, callbackDelay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can reliably predict the end of user interaction in this manner, but that aside, you could do something like this:

```
var cancelToken;
$("#myButton").click(() => {
    cancelToken && clearTimeout(cancelToken);
    cancelToken = setTimeout(() => {
        alert("5 seconds elapsed")
    }, 5000);
});
```

Clicking the button sets a timer that is cancelled & renewed each time the button is clicked.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oop5wyxL/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use (click) event handler and use a timeout to do the call. When a click is done, you reset the counter. So, you can set the counter to the time you think is correct to ensure the user stopped clicking. Something like this:

html

```
<button (click)="saveBasket()">
```

js

```
timer;

saveBasket(){
    if (this.timer) { // RESET THE TIMER IN EVERY CLICK
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(callAPI(), 10000); // CALL THE API AFTER 10 SECONDS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea you're describing is similar to debouncing; but this isn't a typical use case for such an approach.

Well, if you really want to do it, I suppose you could use a timeout.  So in the handler for clicking on Add, set a timeout that waits a short time and then sends the request to the server.  (Before setting the timeout for this click, remember to cancel any timeouts from previous clicks or it's all for naught.)  But then you also have to watch out for the user navigating away before the timeout expires...

In an angular app, why should a quantity change require a server call anyway?  Isn't there something like "submit order" that the user will click once all quantities are set?  Is the server call just so the server can recalculate a price to display?  If so, do that client-side; that's why you use angular.